# Jenkins job trigger when s3 bucket updated

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I am looking for a way to trigger the Jenkins job whenever the s3 bucket is updated with a particular file format.

I have tried a lambda function method with an "Add trigger -> s3 bucket PUT method". I have followed this [article](https://sandrocirulli.net/aws-lambda-and-jenkins-integration/). But it's not working. I have explored and I have found out that "AWS SNS" and "AWS SQS" also can use for this, but the problem is some are saying this is outdated. So which is the simplest way to trigger the Jenkins job when the s3 bucket is updated?

I just want a trigger, whenever the zip file is updated from job A in jenkins1 to the S3 bucket name called 'testbucket' in AWS enviornment2. Both Jenkins are in different AWS accounts under seperate private VPC. I have attached my Jenkins workflow as a picture. Please refer below picture.
[image]

Comment: You need to enable VPC peering between your accounts. This documentation may help to do it; https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/peer-with-vpc-in-another-account.html

Comment: I have already made a connection between these AWS environments. That's working fine. Now I want to trigger the Jenkins job when the s3 bucket is updated. I have round-marked on the right side of the picture, that's the trigger I want.

Comment: Ah I see, I got it in wrong way sorry about that. Maybe you can consider to enabling versioning and changing event type as "All object create events" in trigger if "put" operation is not trackable in your case.

Answer (score 0):

The approach you are using seems solid and a good way to go. I'm not sure what specific issue you are having so I'll list a couple things that could explain why this might not be working for you:

- Permissions issue - Check to ensure that the Lambda can be invoked by the S3 service. If you are doing this in the console (manually) then you probably don't have to worry about that since the permissions should be automatically setup. If you're doing this through infrastructure as code then it's something you need to add.
- Lambda VPC config - Your lambda will need to run out of the same subnet in your VPC that the Jenkins instance runs out of. Lambda by default will not be associated to a VPC and will not have access to the Jenkins instance (unless it's publicly available over the internet).

I found this other stackoverflow post that describes the SNS/SQS setup if you want to continue down that path [Trigger Jenkins job when a S3 file is updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45585748/trigger-jenkins-job-when-a-s3-file-is-updated)

Comment: I am using the lambda console only to create the trigger. I am using the python code provided in my question link. created a test configure event including trigger event "s3 PUT". when I test in the lambda console its throws this error - [ERROR] AttributeError: module 'importlib._bootstrap' has no attribute 'SourceFileLoader'. Lamba and instance are in the same vpc only.